# Computational effects of iteratively slicing an array

Tags: python, numpy

If I take a slice of a slice of a slice... of a numpy array, am I creating a deeply nested data structure?

Outline of what I'm asking about:

```
data = np.rand(1024)

while more_to_do(data):
     removed_value = select_item(data)
     # use slicing to "remove" a particular value from the array
     data = data[data!=removed_value]

# Another way to ask the question, would be
# does indexing into data after taking
# all of these slices, e.g. calling 

value = data[5]

# take time proportional to the number of iterations 
# through the loop?
```

The actual context is in a particular implementation of a [concave hull](http://repositorium.sdum.uminho.pt/bitstream/1822/6429/1/ConcaveHull_ACM_MYS.pdf) algorithm  that uses this kind of slicing to iteratively remove points from consideration as they are selected as part of the hull.

Comment: I think the answer is `No`. After the loop, your `data` is just a simple numpy array.  `value=data[5]` is just a normal slicing. It might be a little slower, since your `data` now might not be continuous on the memory but that should be irrelevant to the `while` loop.

Comment: If the indexing can't create a `view`, then the result is a `copy`.  A copy has its own data buffer, without any 'memory' of the original array.  (re)read basic numpy docs that show data layout, with particular focus on how an array consists of `shape`, `strides`, `dtype` and a 1d data buffer (which might be shared with other arrays).